# Why does my encryption module return different values if im in jruby instead of ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, aes, jruby

I have written a very basic encryption module that I am using to encrypt some values in a .yaml file.

```
require 'OpenSSL'
require 'Base64'

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :CBC)
cipher.key = ENV['KEY']
cipher.iv = ENV['IV']
cipher.encrypt
encrypted = cipher.update(ARGV[0]) + cipher.final
p Base64.encode64(encrypted).gsub!(/\n/,'')
```

If I run the encryptor like so, I get one value

```
rvm use jruby-9.0.5.0    
jruby encryptor.rb 'password'
4cP7jptj5Z14c2KoXdNf+g==
```

If I run the encryptor like this, I receive a different value

```
rvm use ruby-2.2.0    
ruby encryptor.rb 'password'
y5ZdDfAGRmK1wQy2e4EOIA==
```

Im relatively new to encryption, so this may be a loaded (or simple) question, but why does my module return two different values depending on what interpreter im using?

**EDIT:** The key is 32-bytes, and I have changed the IV to be 16-bytes, and the results still differ between interpreters.

EXAMPLE KEYS:

```
key = 1DR337Z5C5CBD94643L9772F96C546AC  
iv  = 2BR367Z5R5CFD949
```

Comment: @zaph just added them to the question

Comment: How is the input padding being handled in each?

Comment: When I use the above inputs key = "1DR337Z5C5CBD94643L9772F96C546AC",  iv = "2BR367Z5R5CFD94: data" "password" with PKCS#7 padding I get: "4cP7jptj5Z14c2KoXdNf+g==".

Comment: @zaph, I get the smae when i run it with jruby 9.0.5.0 - 4cP7jptj5Z14c2KoXdNf+g==, then if i run it with ruby 2.2.0 I get y5ZdDfAGRmK1wQy2e4EOIA==

Comment: @zaph good point, updated the question. Also I am going to see what the library offers in terms of specifying padding.

Comment: I suspect that ruby and jruby are using different padding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With OpenSSL, when you call `cipher.encrypt` you reset the key and the iv (or at least change the internal state of the `cipher` object in some way). There is a Ruby bug about this: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8720

The [JRuby OpenSSL emulation layer](https://github.com/jruby/jruby-openssl) doesn’t seem to have this behaviour, and gives the same result wherever you have the call to `cipher.encrypt`.

The workaround / fix is to ensure the call to `cipher.encrypt` occurs *before* you set the key and iv:

```
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = ENV['KEY']
cipher.iv = ENV['IV']
```

Answer (score 0):

Supply full length values for the key and IV.

In the case of the key you need 256-bits (32-bytes).

In the case of the IV the length needs to be the block size which is (for AES) 16-bytes.

If the inputs are to short there is not standard on how to handle this and each implementation may choose different methods such as null padding or just using whatever bytes immediately follow the supplied values.

Comment: We don't have the actual values, he's getting them from the ENV hash

Comment: yep, and I can confirm that both the key and the iv are the exact same length

Comment: The key and IV should not be the same length since you are using a 32-byte key.

Comment: @Artjom the key is 32-bytes, and iv is 16-bytes

Comment: @zaph just tried changing the iv to 16-bytes, and still the same deal.